# New command dynTable not working in a subfile

Tags: macros, exam

I am trying to write an exam in Overleaf. I am using subfiles so I have a structure of MainFile.tex which includes a bunch of subfiles. This has been working well. I have struck a problem when I want to add a final page that will show a multiple choice answer sheet. This page contains a /newcommand (code I found on stackexchange). The new command works well when I compile the individual page - I get the following :[image]

however when I try recomiling the main page I get an error

[image].

My code is :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,addpoints]{exam} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\parindent 0em     % no indenting on para
% \printanswers


\usepackage{subfiles}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document} 

% font family for entire document
% \sffamily      
% \subfile{./sections/title}              % PRINT THE TITLE PAGE
% \pagebreak
% \subfile{./sections/multipleChoice}     % PRINT THE MULTIPLE CHOICE PART
\pagebreak
%\subfile[sections/longanswer.tex]

% \subfile{./sections/longQuestionsSetup.tex}     % get setup for the long question format
% %this rule formats the long question Question line
% \qformat{\parbox{\textwidth}{Question \thequestion{} (\totalpoints{} marks) \hfill  \vspace*{0.5cm}}}


%\subfile{./sections/headerPage}
```

% \subfile{./sections/multiplechoice}
\newpage
%\subfile{./sections/longAnswer}  % NOW PRODUCE THE LONG ANSWER PART OF

```
\pagebreak

\subfile{./sections/multiChoiceTearoff}

\pagebreak
\vspace{3cm}
\large 
\center
\textbf{End of Exam}

\pagebreak

\newpage
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\baselineskip=10mm
\parskip=0pt
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\InitToks}{\toks@={}}
\newcommand{\AddToks}[1]{\toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@ #1}}
\newcommand*{\PrintToks}{\the\toks@}
\unitlength=1mm
\def\BOX{\framebox(7 ,7){}}
\newcount\rowNo

\newcommand*{\dynTable}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \InitToks
    \AddToks{\tabcolsep=0pt\begin{tabular}{c*{5}{>{\centering}p{10mm}}}}%
    \AddToks{&&A&B&C&D \tabularnewline}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \rowNo=0 %
    \loop\ifnum\rowNo<#1\relax
      \advance\rowNo by 1
      \AddToks{\strobe & }
      \expandafter\AddToks\expandafter{%
         \the\rowNo & 
         \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX %& \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX & \BOX%
        \tabularnewline}%
    \repeat
   \AddToks{\end{tabular}}%
    \PrintToks
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\def\strobe{\rule{0pt}{4mm}\rule{3mm}{2.54mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
    \raggedright
    \Large{\textbf{Student Number}}
    %\large{\Student Number}\\
    \huge
    \begin{tabular}{| p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.5cm} |}
        \hline
         & & & & & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm}
\sffamily\Large

 \textbf{My subject name}
 
 \textbf{Assessment Task - 2023}
 
\textbf{Answer Sheet}

\bigskip
\textbf{Section I - Multiple Choice}

\bigskip
Tick the letter that corresponds to the correct answer. If you make a change clearly indicate which answer is correct.


\dynTable{10}


\end{document}
```

Comment: We do not have access to your subfiles nor the definition of `\dynTable`, could you please make your code compilable? You can use `\begin{filecontents}` to put the subfiles in your code here, it is impossible to help otherwise

Comment: @JamesT - Sorry, I somehow left the most important bit out. I have now modded the question to include the dynTable